# How do I load a youtube video page, without reloading the whole page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm making a Chrome extension and I'm trying to add functionality of adding my own youtube video suggestion panels to youtube pages, so clickable elements on youtube which take user to a videopage.
Behaviour should be exactly same as if clicking on the videos on youtube: *because it's an SPA, the page is **not** refreshed, but videopage replaces a part of the DOM.*

First thing I tried was doing
`window.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-ioG4KEVyc"`, [but this is too naive and the whole page gets reloaded(duh)](https://streamable.com/s6nuvi).

How would one go about making youtube load the video page from a link without reloading the whole page when I don't have access to the underlying angular app?

Comment: I tried history.pushState, doesn't seem to work (does absolutely nothing except changing the URL bar). Is there anything wrong with having a full refresh?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Thanks. Yeah, two downsides to a full refresh:  
1. my content script is unloaded and loaded again, which means losing variables, and 2. a big loss in user experience, as it's simply not as fast/smooth to fully reload a page.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be displaying a youtube embed.

Youtube videos have a feature that allows you to embed the video into your page.
You can display/load the embed when the user clicks on your link.

I don't believe loading a full youtube page without refreshing/redirecting is possible. You can try using an [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to load youtube, however, I'm not sure that will load the video with all the scripts, functions, etc.